# what does the phrase "get someone into something" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am reading a text. A line of it, is as follows:

Your daughter has a cocaine habit. ***Get her into rehab.***

I have searched about the meaning of "get someone into something" and I found somethings. But I am not sure yet about the exact meaning of "get her into rehab". does it mean try to persuade her to start rehabilitation? or does it mean "take her to a rehabilitation center"? or the meaning is something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Get someone into something" can have several meanings, depending on the context.

In this case, an accurate reading might be "make sure that she starts rehabilitation." This could be a program or it could be a literal center. You're right that "get her into rehab" makes it sound like they might be referring to an actual rehabilitation center with a building she can go inside.

Sometimes "get someone into something" means to make the person interested in something, usually referring to a hobby or a TV show or an interest. Here, rehabilitation isn't really a fun hobby or interest, so this is probably not the best meaning. "Get her into rehab" is quite a strong way to suggest (or even command) someone to make their daughter go to rehab, so this phrasing was probably chosen to convey urgency ("If you possibly can, get her into rehab as soon as possible).

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that in this particular case, saying somebody is "in rehab" is a very common way to say that somebody is getting treatment for an addiction, even if they are not physically "in" anywhere.  This, I believe, comes from the fact that, more than many other kinds of treatment, there has been a long history of addiction rehab facilities where part of the process is to sequester people away from the rest of the world for part or all of their treatment.